# Restricted web page can be accessed via URL

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

*Hello guys, Please be kind enough to tell me my errors as this is my first stackoverflow post...*
So, I was creating a small API to access my ESP32 development board from the Internet. I have created that successfully, but, anyone who visits my website can talk to my ESP. I want to create a login page that asks for a Uname and Pword that are stored in a MySQL database. Then, I want it to redirect to my main API page **only if** uname and pword are typed in correctly. I have already done something like this, but if anyone types the URL of the API page, example.com/esp-control or something the whole ESP control page can be accessed. If there would be any way to mitigate this issue, I would really like to know how. Thank you.

Comment: If you just redirect to an unprotected URL after you checked the credentials, then of course anyone can access the actual target URL directly. There is currently way too little actually useful information here, to tell what could be done instead. We don't know what your API is implemented _in_, whether it could for example access a PHP session, ...

Comment: So your API is like an office with no locks. And your redirect system is like a locked drawer with a piece of paper that has the address of the office written on it. There's no need to go into the drawer if you already know the address of the office Put locks on the office doors.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The API is just a web page with HTML and CSS and it has an API custom built into it. It has a bunch of text boxes and switches... and it is just a .php file with the html and API code. I want people to access this file if they know the Pword and Uname of the login page...